Vnstat reporting large amounts of traffic
Ubuntu 24.04
Vnstat ver: 2.12
Vnstat some days reports very high traffic different than provider.
On 24 Jun reports
hour        rx      tx      total
07:00        3.10 GIB        3.95 GIB          7.05 GIB
Total for the day  8.43 GiB
The provider reports total 1862 MB
Can some help to correct this
Thank you

Are you using default settings or have some parts of the configuration file been changed?
